# Why cant @ViewChild run outside AfterViewInit?

Tags: angular, viewchild, elementref

so I am trying to do some events base on the scrolling of my Angular application.

I have a problem since I am trying to access a element in my HTML with the help of `@ViewChild`.

I can access the element inside `ngAfterViewInit()` but I can't access it outside of it. It always shows undefined.

Here is my component class:

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('navBar')
  navBar:ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, true);
    console.log(this.navBar.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onScroll(){
    console.log("I am scrolling right now.")
    console.log(this.navBar.nativeElement)
  }

  onResize(){

  }

  onTabClick(){

  }
}
```

When i console log inside `ngAfterViewInit()` i get the HTML element but when i console log inside `onScroll()` it is undetfined.

Why does my element disappears and gets undefined after viewinit? I am not using any `ngIf` or anything that removes the element.

Here is the component HTML code.

```
  <section class="et-hero-tabs" >
    <h1>STICKY SLIDER NAV</h1>
    <h3>Sliding content with sticky tab nav</h3>
    <div class="et-hero-tabs-container" #navBar>
      <a class="et-hero-tab" href="">ES6</a>
      <a class="et-hero-tab" href="">Flexbox</a>
      <a class="et-hero-tab" href="">React</a>
      <a class="et-hero-tab" href="">Angular</a>
      <a class="et-hero-tab" href="">Other</a>
      <span class="et-hero-tab-slider"></span>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Here is the console error:
[image]

Comment: The problem is the way you call `this.onScroll`. To preserve `this`, you can: (1) define the callback as an arrow function: `onScroll = () => { ... }`, or (2) wrap the call inside an arrow function: `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { this.onScroll(); }, true);`.

Comment: you can use also rxjs "fromEvent":https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent. `fromEvent(window,'scroll').subscribe(res=>{...})` this allow you unsubscribe, or delay or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the meaning of `this` keyword in the callback function using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method. Try the following

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);
  console.log(this.navBar.nativeElement);
}
```

Without binding, the scope of `this` keyword in the `onScroll()` callback doesn't point to scope of the class.

Comment: I understand what happens now with this answer. But is there a reason why the variable gets undefined? In my case "navBar" ? Maybe what i am asking is: If is defined once, why is it not always defined?

Comment: When you pass the callback directly, `this` keyword would point to scope of the function. And in the function there isn't any `navBar` variable. Using `bind(this)`, you could tell the callback to use `this` from the scope of `ngAfterViewInit()` function which would point to the class.

Comment: Oh, alright. So i am basically giving the class context to the function. But how come i can log other class variables? Sorry for my dumb questions. I understand what u meant i am just trying to understand why the only possible way to access that variable is on the scope of AfterViewInit.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to access any member variables without the reference to `this`. Unless the variables are defined inside the function.